# Calculate fastest growth of population function $P(t)= \frac{50000}{1+1000e^{−0.5t}}$

Tags: calculus

A small population of wasps is observed. After t weeks the population is modelled by $$P(t)= \frac{50000}{1+1000e^{−0.5t}}$$ wasps, where 0 ⩽t ⩽ 25. Find when the wasp population is growing fastest.

I first differentiated this equation once and equated it to 0. However, I am not able to solve it further as I just get: $$e^{−0.5t} = 0$$

I'm not so sure whether there might be something wrong with my method or whether there is any other way of approaching this problem.

Comment: differentiate twice not once since you need the maximum gradient

Comment: When do I know I should differentiate it once or twice (as for other problems like finding the maximum area of a rectangle given its perimeter and one side, I usually set the first derivative to 0 and only to check and I take the second derivative to see whether the shape’s concave up or down and based on this decide the minimum or maximum point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate at which the wasp population is growing is given by
$$
P'(t) = \frac{25000000 e^{-\frac{t}{2}}}{\left(1000 e^{-\frac{t}{2}}+1\right)^2}.
$$
We want to find the value of $t$ that maximizes this function. Since $P'$ is continuous on $[0,25]$ and differentiable on $(0,25)$, this must occur at a boundary point ($t=0$ or $t=25$) or at a point such that $P''(t)=0$. We evaluate $P$ at the boundary points:
\begin{align}
P'(0) &= \frac{25000000}{1002001}\approx 24.95007\\
\quad P'(25) &= \frac{25000000}{\left(1+\frac{1000}{e^{25/2}}\right)^2 e^{25/2}}\approx 92.47579,
\end{align}
then compute the derivative:
$$
P''(t) = \frac{12500000 e^{t/2} \left(1000-e^{t/2}\right)}{\left(e^{t/2}+1000\right)^3}.
$$
We see that $P''(t)= 0$ if and only if $12500000 e^{t/2} \left(1000-e^{t/2}\right)=0$, and since the first factor is always positive, this is the case if and only if $e^{t/2}=1000$. Taking logs and solving for $t$ yields $t= 2\log1000\approx 13.81551$. Since $P''$ is positive on $[0,2\log1000)$ and negative on $(2\log1000,25]$, it follows that $t=2\log1000$ is a local (and hence global) maximum for $P'$.

Comment: shouldn't it be $t = 2ln1000 \approx 13.82$ ?

Comment: @Steven31415 You are correct, I copied the wrong number. I have fixed it now.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The growth is the fastest when the slope of $P(t)$ is the largest. Evaluate $
P'(t) = \frac{ke^{-t/2}}{\left(1000 e^{-t/2}+1\right)^2}$, with $k=25mm$. Then, cast it in the form

$$P'(t) = \frac k{(1000e^{-t/4}-e^{t/4})^2+2000}\le \frac k{2000}$$

where the equality, or, the maximal growth, occurs at $1000e^{-t/4}=e^{t/4}$, i.e. $t=2\ln 1000$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you!